# how to overwrite link_to_route in laravel 4?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I use

```
link_to_route('route.name', $title, $parameters = array(), $attributes = array());
```

to generate HTML a tag. such as

```
link_to_route('page', 'I am a dog', array('id'=> '12'), $attributes = array());
```

Now, I tried to do some pre-process. I had a mapping table which save page id and the alias.
such as `12 => dog, 13 => cat`.

Thus,the example link would actually transferred to

```
link_to_route('dog', 'I am a dog', array('id'=> '12'), $attributes = array());
```

Could anyone give me an hint how to overwrite the method?
Since I don not want to modify the code in the illuminate helper file, I need a more elegant way.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think the only way is to define such function BEFORE helpers are loaded. So if you don't want to use Laravel functionality for creating this function, you may even create it in `public/index.php` (or of course include file with implementation of this method) right at the beginning of the file and Laravel obviously won't overwrite it.

Answer (score 0):

You can re-define your own `link_to_route()` wherever you want, and add that script at composer.json. `link_to_route` is tested if exists so you wont cause any problem by that.

You can edit `link_to_route()` which lives on `vendor/illuminate`

Or you can define another functions which uses `linkRoute` and use it's response to make your own HTML.

Hope that helps.